# Want to extract substring JNDSKSJD from string RXSAPI=\"JNDSKSJD\" in TCL and save in another variable

Tags: regex, tcl

I want to extract JNDSKSJD from string RXSAPI="JNDSKSJD`" in TCL using regexp.
SUbstring between characters "

Comment: Please be more specific.  What do you mean by "extract"?

Do you want to confirm that "JNDSKSJD" is part of your string?  

or do you want to identify an unknown word in double quotes, which is JNDSKSJ in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Making a few small assumptions:

```
if {[regexp {RXSAPI=\"(\w+)} $inputString -> substring]} {
    puts "I found $substring in $inputString"
} else {
    puts "I did not find anything"
}
```

Comment: The assumptions? I assumed that `RXSAPI` was constant, that it needed no word boundary constraints, that there was no whitespace to confound, and that we're interested in the sequence of all word characters after the double quote.

Comment: yes, RXSAPI is constant. My requirement is to find substring  between \" .
For example , i have a string  RXSAPI=\"JNDSKSJD\"
and i want substring JNDSKSJD  saved onto another variable. All other characters are constant and will not change